Delete and stop tracking folders from client branch but keep them on main product branch
I've branch out client branch (C) from main product (P) branch which I am adding features as per request. The main product branch contains all folders/files for every client with the main product code.
Is there a way to delete and stop tracking other clients' folders in branch C but can still merge C to P without P removing the folders?
I've tried git rm for the unwanted folders and adding them in .gitignore in C branch, but when I try to merge P is deleting them as well.

What you are looking for is sparse checkout. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

you mention that your branch P has the code for all clients (which IMHO is a good thing). Is your intention to create one dedicated branch per client ?

my blind guess: you would like to deploy "branch C" to production for client C ? and you are dealing with a project in python or php or ruby or ... where the code is the content required to be deployed ?

(as opposed to java or go or ..., where you would need to compile first and copy over the compiled result)

The intention is to have one branch for each client but deploy P in production. Each client has different modules customized for them but they are all based on some common modules. My main concern is to reduce the redundant files

What you are looking for is sparse checkout. git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout – eftshift0
git sparse-checkout set <unwanted-folder>

This resolved my issues since it stops tracking unwanted folders on my checked-out branch but kept them on remote product branch.
git sparse-checkout disable

to disable this configuration on my local environment

Please don't abuse backticks for emphasis. They should be used for inline code, commands, and filenames only.
